# Shared Ip Hosting

Tags: networking, dns, hosting, shared

i am a newbie in the field so i need sm1 to enlight me with authentic knowledge.thanks in advance.

for example 
ns1.bh-17.webhostbox.net

this above nameserver shows various domains that make use of it to resolve to correct host.

so my question is ->suppose some abc.com  uses above nameserver given by hosting provider to bind domain ,
1. what is or how to find  actual ip adress of machine hosting abc.com that have all actual website files?

2. does this ip address is some local lan ip identifying particular machine having abc.com website files or this ip is exposed to internet so any can access it straightaway just typing in the browser from anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

A hosting company can have multiple domains living at the same IP, or various IPs living on the same server.
There are a variety of tools to figure out what domains reside on a given IP address, but access to these is still protected by the hosting company. So to answer:

## 1: You can get this from your webhost, or search who.is to see what IP a domain resides on.

## 2: The Ip is exposed, in that you can type it and (along with the username) view the website, but that isn't really identifying the 'machine' so much, as the IP can be moved from one server to another. It really just let's you view the site normally.

I hope that helps...

Comment: i have come across that cpanel can reflect the server address under status ,so this address is publicly exposed that is any user can ping it - ping (server address here)?

Comment: ...yes, you can ping it - and you can find out the IP of many sites easily and ping those, though you won't know the username of the account. Are you worried about a security threat?